# How do I merge a tex file with the main one?

Tags: include, import, textmerg

So the simplified problem is :

I have a directory called `Main` inside which there is my `main.tex` file.

Then there is another folder called `Supplement` in which there are another file `file1.tex` and a folder named Graph with pictures needed by `file1.tex`.

So when then I  copy the folder `Supplement` in the folder `Main`, and from `main.tex` i use the command `\import{}{Supplement/file1.tex}` BUT now the problem is naturally that the pictures needed by `file1.tex` are not found. So i need to go in `file1.tex` and change the path of the `\includegraphics` command to be `/Supplement/Graph`.

So there is a way in which I can merge a tex file to another without having to change all the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is supposed to be

```
\import{Supplement/}{file1.tex}
```

in which there are commands like

```
\includegraphics{Graph/pretty.pdf}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you include your graphics with `graphics`/`graphicx`, you could add the `Supplement/Graph` to the path which is searched for graphics files:

```
 \graphicspath{Supplement/Graph}
```